# Why my Linq query against SQLite does not return all table field values

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, windows-runtime, sqlite-net

I am building a WinRT application with SQLite.

I am running the following method within my C# code in order to retrieve all columns from a table `ProductSubCategory` which have equal Parent ID

I am using latest version of SQLite.Net and SQLITE.NET.ASync

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductSubCategory>> GetProductSubCategoryAsync(int ParentCategoryId)
{
    List<ProductSubCategory> lst = new List<ProductSubCategory>();
    var DBconn = await _sqliteService.OpenSQLiteConnection();
    {
        //retrive test data
        lst = await DBconn.Table<ProductSubCategory>().Where(c=>c.ParentSubCategoryId==ParentCategoryId).ToListAsync();
    }
    return lst;
}
```

Class Definition :

```
public class ProductCategory:ObservableObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RowGuid { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

When the code execute it returns the correct amount of records based on the filter but not all return field value get returned.

For instance all my table field of type INT as well as primary key is not updated in my object.

Any reason for that and solution to get it to work? I need to retrieve all those column data.

Does it depend on the way field gets created ?

Comment: Please add the class definition for `ProductSubCategory`.

Comment: the productSubCategory class definition exist with same filed name and type. I added the definittion in post above. I need to get the PrimaryKey return in my class field but it is not. Any reason for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find out the problem.
My table database column field which was not returning data was named **ProductCategoryID** and my object name was **ProductCategoryId**

Which means that when to get field from DB, field name are case sensitive but what is strange is that if your insert data they are not.

I have simply rename my table field name to be ProductCategoryID and now I get the data correctly